# Mocha on random build : Hook beforeTest error

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, mocha.js

I am currently on a node.js project with socket.io and I made some tests.

https://github.com/jy95/P4ng/blob/master/test/test.js

In random builds  on travis like this one : https://travis-ci.org/jy95/P4ng/jobs/180385911 , I got this error (go see job log for futher information):

```
1) "before each" hook
```

In beforeEach function , I remove all listeners on my sockets :

I do that because previous tests callbacks were triggered (and I got error done() : called multiple time) when I use same event for different test cases.

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
        // runs before each test in this block

        // removes previously listeners to this two sockets (seen in anothers test)
        for (let socketTest of [socket1,socket2,socket3,socket4] ) {
            if (socketTest !== undefined) {
                socketTest.removeAllListeners();
            }
        }
        done();
    });
```

Can you explain me why I got this ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If all those actions are not asynchronous, then you do not need the `done` callback.

Comment: Also, if you have to clean something of test, it is usually better to do it in the `afterEach` block. `beforeEach` should be user to setup the environment, not to clean.

Comment: All those actions are asynchronous :) I just don't understand why the error happened in the last tests

Comment: Ok, then you need to call `done` only when the actions are completed. You can use either Promises to wrap you async calls, or a callback helper such `async.js`. Once they are all complete (`Promise.all` or `async.each`) then call `done`.

Comment: If I changed it to afterEach , the last test failed ^^

Comment: I had a look at your test code and there are various issues: you're calling `done` often at the wrong moment, and most of the time you're making the setup for the test within the test code itself rather than in the `beforeEach`. Are you sure you need 4 sockets for that? As far as I see each test uses only one socket per time.

Comment: Each test uses average 1-2 sockets. I need to test than 2 remote users received the information for some case (example : joinRoom)